# Replace the first occurrence of a matching text using sed/perl/awk

Tags: perl, unix, sed

I was trying to match the first occurrence of a text in a line and removing it using sed. But I came to know that sed is greedy and it will not work for my case and now I am trying to implement the same using Perl but it is not working.

```
cat test.txt
IAM*WRITNG*THIS*TEXT*FOR*SAMPLE*NUMBER*123*345.05*678987*TEST*OF*DATA*WITH*SOME*DUMMY*TEXT*TO*CHECK*WHETHER*IT*WILL*WORK*TEXT*REPEATING
```

Expected Output:

```
IAM*WRITNG*THIS*TO*CHECK*WHETHER*IT*WILL*WORK*TEXT*REPEATING
```

with SED:

```
sed -e 's/\(TEXT\*.*\*.*\*.*\*.*\*.*\*678987\).*\(TEXT\*\)/\2/' test.txt
```

Output:

```
IAM*WRITNG*THIS*TEXT*REPEATING
```

With Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/\(TEXT\*.*\*.*\*.*\*.*\*.*\*678987\).*?\(TEXT\*\)/\2/' test.txt
```

Output:

```
IAM*WRITNG*THIS*TEXT*FOR*SAMPLE*NUMBER*123*345.05*678987*TEST*OF*DATA*WITH*SOME*DUMMY*TEXT*TO*CHECK*WHETHER*IT*WILL*WORK*TEXT*REPEATING
```

Can someone please let me know what was the mistake that I was doing?

Update: I tried with the solution given for Perl command but it's not working with lines with more length. Is there a way to do this using awk?

Comment: Can you provide the sample `with lines with more length` and the expected output for it to clarify your requirement?

Comment: You said `I was trying to match the first occurrence of a text` - please clearly state in your question what that text string is that you're trying to match. As-is we'd be trying to guess what you do want from reading the scripts you provided that apparently don't do what you want so YMMV.

Comment: There isn't a simple way to do it in Awk.  Using Perl is your best bet.

Comment: Do you know how many sequences of `[^*]*\*` appear after the number and before the second occurrence of TEXT?  If so, it can be coded in `sed`; if not, you need Perl with its non-greedy matching.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike sed, grouping a pattern in Perl requires just a pair of parentheses, not parentheses escaped by backslashes:

```
perl -pe 's/(TEXT\*.*\*.*\*.*\*.*\*.*\*678987).*?(TEXT\*)/$2/' test.txt
```

Comment: Perl command is not working when the lines are with more length. Is there a way to do this using awk ?

Comment: You haven't tagged your question with awk so why are you now asking for an awk solution? And what makes you think an awk solution would fare any better than perl or sed?

Answer (score 3):

You can try following command and see if it fits your requirements

`perl -pe "s/TEXT.*?TEXT.//" test_1.txt`

output

`IAM*WRITNG*THIS*TO*CHECK*WHETHER*IT*WILL*WORK*TEXT*REPEATING`

Comment: I want to match based on TEXT*FOR*SAMPLE*NUMBER*123*345.05*678987. So your solution will not work.

Comment: @Kumar_123 -- sorry, my mistake I looked at your `sed` output instead of _Expected Output_.

Comment: @Kumar_123 -- I made a small change, try new version.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
perl -pe 's/(TEXT\*.*?678987).*?(?=TEXT\*)//' test.txt
```